# Which method is more reliable in determining whether I can install .NET 3.5 Windows features?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I am trying to determine if I can install .NET 3.5 Windows features on a random server (Windows 2016 onwards).

I found online that we can do
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name NetFx3~~~~
(Source: https://woshub.com/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows/)

Or we can do,
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MicrosoftNET Framework Setup\NDPv3.5").Version
(source: https://www.danielengberg.com/install-net-framework-35/)

However, sometimes when I ran as administrator,
Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name NetFx3~~~~
I don't get
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name NetFx3~~~~

Name         : NetFX3~~~~
State        : Installed
DisplayName  : .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
Description  : .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
DownloadSize : 72354590
InstallSize  : 253084958

but rather
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name NetFx3~~~~

Name         :
State        : NotFound
DisplayName  :
Description  :
DownloadSize :
InstallSize  :

so would the registry key be enough to say I can install .Net 3.5 Windows features on the server? If it is the right value?
Or Get-WindowsCapability should be more reliable and it could be something to do with the server that doesn't give me the right results?